# Table not auto create in HeidiSql(mysql) by spring hibernate. And no error shows in console but jdbc details missing, my code details given below

Tags: spring, hibernate

Table not auto create in HeidiSql(mysql) by spring hibernate. And no error shows in console but jdbc details missing,  my code details given below

### Model class

my entity java class
@Entity

@Table(name = "Payment_Table")

public class Payment implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 4501753715497967062L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;
private String transactionId;
private String vendor;
private Date paymentDate;
private double amount;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTransactionId() {
    return transactionId;
}

public void setTransactionId(String transactionId) {
    this.transactionId = transactionId;
}

public String getVendor() {
    return vendor;
}

public void setVendor(String vendor) {
    this.vendor = vendor;
}

public Date getPaymentDate() {
    return paymentDate;
}

public void setPaymentDate(Date paymentDate) {
    this.paymentDate = paymentDate;
}

public double getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public void setAmount(double amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}

public Payment() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Payment(String transactionId, String vendor, Date paymentDate, double amount) {
    super();
    this.transactionId = transactionId;
    this.vendor = vendor;
    this.paymentDate = paymentDate;
    this.amount = amount;
}
```

}

### application-context.xml

my data base configuration

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.spring.rest.curd.model.Payment</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernet.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

### web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<display-name>Spring Rest Application</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springRest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springRest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

### springRest-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.rest.curd.*"></context:component-scan>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<tx:annotation-driven />
```